# Mac shortcut for next window - IDE 1.8.7 problem

Tags: arduino-ide, mac-os

How do I use the keyboard to cycle through Arduino windows on a mac?

In my System preferences, I have (default):

`Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts` -> `Move focus to next window` =  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>

It works perfectly in all other programs, but in the Arduino IDE, it only swaps between the last two windows. If I have three(or more) windows open, it is a real pain to find the one in the background.

I am using fully updated MacOS 10.14 and Arduino IDE 1.8.7

Comment: That shortcut works for me. Which version of the IDE and OSX are you using?

Comment: @VE7JRO: See edit. Have you tried to cycle through three or more windows?

Comment: Yes, I am able to cycle through 3 or more windows. I am using an old version of OSX and an old version the IDE.

Comment: @VE7JRO: Thank you for your help. I now found that by adding shift (normally used for reverse cycle), I can get all windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MacOS 10.14 and Arduino IDE 1.6.12, <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> cycles through 5+ IDE windows properly, for me.

Update:

> When you upgrade to Arduino 1.8.7,

I won't be. I've tried a couple of its point releases and have given up on it because its launch performance is so p...-poor. Maybe 1.9 will finally fix it.

Sloeber/Eclipse is my serious code-crunching IDE. I keep the A-IDE around for reference and for quick knock-off experiments because it's quick to launch.

Update 2:

The OP asked me to note that he

> found that  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>  cycles
>   through *all* windows (maybe in reverse).

Update 3:

> In older IDE the reverse cycling with Shift doesn't work?

It works in both directions for me (shifted/unshifted).

Comment: My comment is gone. I did not delete it myself - I have no idea what is happening. Could you add the workaround for IDE 1.8.7 - for completeness?

Comment: In older IDE the reverse cycling with Shift doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Just by trying, I found that  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift</kbd>   <kbd>`</kbd>  cycles through *all* windows (maybe in reverse).

Comment: So cmd ` doesn't work on current IDE but cmd shift ` does? Shift should only change direction.

Comment: @Juraj: I do not know why you find it hard to understand, or why you reject a well meant edit. JRoberts and I found the same thing: in the new IDE 1.8.7 cmd+` does not work(as expected) while cmd+shift+` does. Now JRobert has made the change, that collects and completes the answer.

Comment: JRobert has only old IDE, he can't confirm your problem with new IDE, where according to you only the reverse cycling works as expected. (you should add the update about reverse cycling to the question)

Comment: @Juraj: I can not figure out if you are trolling. Please go ahead and change what you want - I will not be spending more time on this.